# Porque no sirven mis funciones en java?

Tags: java, array

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que se supone que debe hacer mi codigo pero no logro hacer funcionar las opciones de baja y cambio, en ambas es el mismo error al momento de entrar a las funciones trabaja con los vectores vacíos.
Siempre que entra a cualquier función que no sea alta o imprimir, al momento de hacer cualquier operación con los vectores trabaja con ellos como si estuvieran vacíos, no se si me explique altere un poco el código para ver que es lo que hace en algunas funciones, no se si explique bien mi duda.
agradecería mucho su ayuda

[image: Como pueden ver se supone que debe haber ya un registro, pero al momento de querer hacer una operacion con el vectores sale nulo]

````
import java.io.*;


public class OP_Basicas {
    void menu() {
        System.out.println("Operaciones basicas con vectores");
        System.out.println("******************** MENU ********************");
        System.out.println("1.     Altas");
        System.out.println("2.     Bajas");
        System.out.println("3.     Cambios");
        System.out.println("4.     Reportes");
        System.out.println("5.     Salir");
        System.out.println("Ingrese una opcion valida   ");
    }
    
    int matricula[] = new int [5]; // vector de matricula y alumno
     String alumno[]= new String[5];
    
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        OP_Basicas op = new OP_Basicas(); // creo el objeto op_basicas para usar los metodos 
        Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n,o;
        int c=0;
        boolean r=false;
        
        do {
            op.menu();// mando a llamar el menu para que se impirma
            o = leer.nextInt();
            switch(o) {// evaluo a donde quiere ir
            case 1:
                c=op.altas(c); // creo una variable llamada C la cual me dice cuantos alumnos se gan registrado
                r=false;
                break;
            case 2:
                c=op.bajas(c);
                r=false;
                r=false;
                break;
            case 3:
                op.cambio(c);
                r=false;
                r=false;
                break;
            case 4:
                op.imprimir();
                r=false;
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Adios");
                r=true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Ingrese opcion valida");
                break;
            }
            
        }while(r==false);

    }
    /* Esta funcion es la de latas la cual recibe como parametro el contador c y lo que hace es primero con un if
     *  checa si ya esta el limite del vector el cual puse en 20
     *  en dado caso que aun quede espacio ingresas el nombre y matricula 
     *  los cuales son enviados a otra funcion que evalua si ya existenpreviamente andes de agregarse a la lista*/
    int altas(int indice) { 
        int c=indice;
        Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean r=false;
        OP_Basicas op = new OP_Basicas();
        if(indice>alumno.length-1){
            System.out.println("Ya ingreso la cantidad maxima de alumnos");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre ");
            String nom=leer.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese la matricula");
            int mat=leer.nextInt();
            r=op.comprobar(nom,mat);
            if(r==true) {
                 alumno[c]=nom;
                 matricula[c]=mat;
                 c++;
            }else {
                System.out.println("El nombre o la matricula ingresados ya existe");
            }
           
        }
        return c;
    }
    /* Esta funcion es la de latas la cual recibe como parametro el contador c y lo que hace es primero con un if
     *  checa si existen registros, en dado caso que no existan lo que haces es lanzar un mensaje 
     *  diciendo que no hay nada registrado
     *  despues si existe el regustro lo que hace es preguntar si lo quiere borrar o no 
     *  despues con un cilo for lo que hago es recorrer todos los datos guardados para asi borrar el seleccionado*/
    int bajas(int indice) {
        int c=indice;
        Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);
        int ni;
        boolean r=false;
        OP_Basicas op = new OP_Basicas();
        switch(indice) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("No tiene ningun alumno registrado");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Ingrese matricula ");
            int num=leer.nextInt();
            r=op.cM(indice);
            if(r==true) {
                ni = op.comprobarM(num);
                System.out.println(alumno[ni]+" Realmente quiere darse de baja SI o NO");
                String d= leer.nextLine();
                    for(int j=ni;j<indice-1;j++){
                     alumno[j]=alumno[j+1];
                     matricula[j]=matricula[j+1];
                    }
                 System.out.println("Alumno borrado con exito");
                  c--;  
            }else {
                System.out.println("No existe la matricula");
            }
            break;
        }
        return c;
    }
    /* Este tiene la misma logica que los anteriores primero comprueba que existan datos guardados
     * despues ingresas la matricula y en cuanto la encuentra te pide el nuevo nombre para ingresar
     * comprueba si ya existe el nombre y si no existe lo actualiza */
    
    void cambio(int indice) {
        int ni;
        Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean r=false;
        OP_Basicas op = new OP_Basicas();
        if(indice==0){
            System.out.println("No tiene ningun alumno registrado");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Ingrese la matricula ");
            int mat=leer.nextInt();
            r=op.cM(indice);
            if(r==false) {
                ni = op.comprobarM(mat);
                System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre ");
                String nom=leer.nextLine();
                if(r==false) {
                    alumno[ni]=nom;
                    System.out.println("Alumno actualizado");
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Nombre ya en uso");
                }
                
                 
            }else {
                System.out.println("El nombre o la matricula ingresados no existe");
            }
           
        }
    }
   /* Esta funcion solo usa un ciclo for para imprimir */
    void imprimir() {
        for(int i=0;i<alumno.length;i++) {
           System.out.println("Alumno: "+alumno[i]+" Matricula: "+matricula[i]);
        }
    }
    /* Esta funcion lo que hace atravez de un for checar registro por registro y si encuentra una coincidencia 
     * retorna un valor booleano de true y si no encuentra nada un false*/
    boolean comprobar(String nom,int mat) {
        boolean r=true;
        for(int i=0;i<alumno.length;i++){
            System.out.println("Alumno: "+alumno[i]+" Matricula: "+matricula[i]);
            if(nom.equals(alumno[i]) || mat==matricula[i]) {
                r=false;
                return r;
            }    
         }
        return r;
    }
    /* Esta funcion lo que hace atravez de un for checar registro por registro y si encuentra una coincidencia 
     * retorna un valor booleano de true y si no encuentra nada un false*/
    boolean cM(int mat) {
        boolean r=false;
        for(int i=0;i<alumno.length;i++){

            if( mat==matricula[i]) {
                r=true;
                return r;
            }    
         }
        return r;
    }
    boolean cN(String nom) {
        boolean r=false;
        for(int i=0;i<alumno.length;i++){

            if(nom.equals(alumno[i])) {
                r=true;
                return r;
            }    
         }
        return r;
    }
    /* Esta funcion lo que hace atravez de un for checar registro por registro y si encuentra una coincidencia 
     * retorna un valor que indica en que parte esta guardado el nombre */
    int comprobarN(String nom) {
        int r=0;
        for(int i=0;i<alumno.length;i++){
            if(nom.equalsIgnoreCase(alumno[i])) 
                r=i;
            }
            return r;
    }
    /* Esta funcion lo que hace atravez de un for checar registro por registro y si encuentra una coincidencia 
     * retorna un valor que indica en que parte esta guardado la matricula */
    int comprobarM(int mat) {
        int r=0;
        for(int i=0;i<matricula.length;i++){
            if(matricula[i]==mat) 
                r=i;
            }
            return r;
    }
        
} ```
````

Comment: Estás creando un nuevo objeto `new OP_Basicas();` en cada función, por eso los vectores están vacíos. Con el objeto que creas en el main debes trabajar.

Comment: crea una solo new Op_Basicas(); y declararlo como static

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que tener en cuenta es que cada vez que realizas `new OP_Basicas();` estas creando un objeto nuevo de clase OP_Basicas por ello solo debe existir un `new OP_Basicas()` en tu programa.
Cuando validas una variable de tipo boolean es inncesario hacer lo siguiente

```
boolean r=true;
if(r==true)
```

debido a que la condicional if el valor de salida es true o false y la variable r es un boolean, entonces es mejor hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
boolean r=true;
if(r) //cuando queremos decir que el valor es true

if(!r)  //cuando queremos decir que el valor es false
```

Ahora yendo a la solución de tu programa, he realizado algunos cambios a tu código inicial.

```
public class OP_Basicas {
    int menu() {
        Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);        
        System.out.println("Operaciones basicas con vectores");
        System.out.println("******************** MENU ********************");
        System.out.println("1.     Altas");
        System.out.println("2.     Bajas");
        System.out.println("3.     Cambios");
        System.out.println("4.     Reportes");
        System.out.println("5.     Salir");
        System.out.println("Ingrese una opcion valida   ");        
        return leer.nextInt();
    }
    
    int cantidad=0;//para llevar el control de cuantos alumnos están registrados
    int matricula[] = new int [5]; // vector de matricula
    String alumno[]= new String[5];// vector que guarda el nombre del alumno
    Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        OP_Basicas op = new OP_Basicas(); // creo el objeto op_basicas para usar los metodos         
        int o;        
        boolean r=false;
        
        do {            
            o = op.menu();
            switch(o) {
            case 1:
                op.altas();  
                break;
            case 2:
               op.bajas(); 
                break;
            case 3:
                op.cambio();
                break;
            case 4:
                op.imprimir();
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Adios");
                r=true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Ingrese opcion valida");
                break;
            }
            
        }while(!r);

    }
    /* Esta funcion es la de latas la cual recibe como parametro el contador c y lo que hace es primero con un if
     *  checa si ya esta el limite del vector el cual puse en 20
     *  en dado caso que aun quede espacio ingresas el nombre y matricula 
     *  los cuales son enviados a otra funcion que evalua si ya existenpreviamente andes de agregarse a la lista*/
    void altas() {        
        boolean r;       
        if(cantidad>alumno.length-1){
            System.out.println("Ya ingreso la cantidad maxima de alumnos");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre ");
            String nom=leer.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese la matricula");
            int mat=leer.nextInt();
            leer.nextLine();
            r=comprobar(nom,mat);
            if(r) {
                alumno[cantidad]=nom;
                matricula[cantidad]=mat;
                cantidad++;
            }else {
                System.out.println("El nombre o la matricula ingresados ya existe");
            }           
        }        
    }
    /* Esta funcion es la de latas la cual recibe como parametro el contador c y lo que hace es primero con un if
     *  checa si existen registros, en dado caso que no existan lo que haces es lanzar un mensaje 
     *  diciendo que no hay nada registrado
     *  despues si existe el regustro lo que hace es preguntar si lo quiere borrar o no 
     *  despues con un cilo for lo que hago es recorrer todos los datos guardados para asi borrar el seleccionado*/
    void bajas() { 
        boolean r;
        int ni;
        if(cantidad==0) {
            System.out.println("No tiene ningun alumno registrado");        
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Ingrese matricula ");
            int num=leer.nextInt();
            leer.nextLine();
            r=cM(num);//verificar que existe la matricula
            if(r){
                ni = comprobarM(num);//obtener en que posición se encuentra la matricula
                System.out.println(alumno[ni]+" Realmente quiere darse de baja Si(s) o NO(n)");
                String borrar= leer.nextLine();
                
                if(borrar.equalsIgnoreCase("s")){
                   matricula[ni]=0;
                   alumno[ni]=null;
                   System.out.println("Alumno borrado con exito");
                   cantidad--;  
                }
                else if (borrar.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
                    System.out.println("No ha borrado al alumno");
                }
                 
            }else {
                System.out.println("No existe la matricula");
            }            
        }        
    }
    /* Este tiene la misma logica que los anteriores primero comprueba que existan datos guardados
     * despues ingresas la matricula y en cuanto la encuentra te pide el nuevo nombre para ingresar
     * comprueba si ya existe el nombre y si no existe lo actualiza */
    
    void cambio() {
        
    }
   /* Esta funcion solo usa un ciclo for para imprimir */
    void imprimir() {
        for(int i=0;i<alumno.length;i++) {
           System.out.println("Alumno: "+alumno[i]+" Matricula: "+matricula[i]);
        }
    }
    /* Esta función lo que hace a través de un for checar registro por registro y si encuentra una coincidencia 
     * retorna un valor booleano de true y si no encuentra nada un false*/
    boolean comprobar(String nom,int mat) {       
        for(int i=0;i<alumno.length;i++){            
            if(nom.equals(alumno[i]) || mat==matricula[i]||mat<=0) {                
                return false;
            }    
        }
        return true;
    }
    /* Esta funcion lo que hace atravez de un for checar registro por registro y si encuentra una coincidencia 
     * retorna un valor booleano de true y si no encuentra nada un false*/
    boolean cM(int mat){        
        for(int i=0;i<alumno.length;i++){
            if( mat==matricula[i]) {                
                return true;
            }    
        }
        return false;
    }
        
    /* Esta funcion lo que hace atravez de un for checar registro por registro y si encuentra una coincidencia 
     * retorna un valor que indica en que parte esta guardado la matricula */
    int comprobarM(int mat) {
        int r=0;
        for(int i=0;i<matricula.length;i++){
            if(matricula[i]==mat) 
                r=i;
        }
            return r;
    }
        
}
```

No re realizado el código para la opción **cambios** para que puedas terminarlo.